# how to test asp.net mvc post actions using MvcContrib.TestHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, routes, mvccontrib-testhelper

I am trying to test my routing configuration using the excellent MvcContrib.TestHelper and I've run into a problem.

Please assume that my Routing Configuration is set up correctly and initialised in the TestFixture.

I have a controller (TransactionsController) action called Create that takes an input parameter of type TransactionRecord:

```
    [Trace, AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(TransactionRecord tx)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Currently my test is as follows:

```
        [Test]
        public void TestRoute_POST_Transactions_Create()
        {
            "~/Transactions/".WithMethod(HttpVerbs.Post).ShouldMapTo<Web.Controllers.TransactionsController>(x => x.Create());
        }
```

My problem is that the Create() method takes a parameter of type TransactionRecord, I do not know how to incorporate this into my test.

I've not been able to find any examples of this nature.

Comment: I just found a similar question that is more eloquently put that mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159589/mvccontrib-test-helper-and-verifying-http-post-routes-and-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the TransactionRecord is created from post data, just pass null to your test:

```
[Test] 
public void TestRoute_POST_Transactions_Create() 
{ 
"~/Transactions/".WithMethod(HttpVerbs.Post).ShouldMapTo<Web.Controllers.Tr ansactionsController>(x 
=> x.Create(null)); 
}
```

Answer courtesy of mvccontrib discussion group:
http://groups.google.com/group/mvccontrib-discuss/browse_thread/thread/2839edd5ad3c5258